# EF DB first update model from DB programmatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning EF DB first, I have updated one table column and I found a solution from the official document to refresh the model.

> Right-click anywhere on the design surface, and select Update Model
>   from Database.

Is there a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any programmatic solution to that?

No.  There is no (common) scenario where updating the model from the database is useful without making manual changes to your code.  So there would be little point in in automating that.